# Discard last 3 characters of a field

Tags: mysql, string

I want to extract the first (not last three) characters of a string from a table like:

```
Code
--------
CREF182
CXEF7U8
CEF7U8
CF777
```

How can I perform a query that will discard the last three characters of the string in a result so it shows something like:

```
Code
--------
CREF
CXEF
CEF
CF
```

I'm thinking this should be the **Opposite of mysql RIGHT** function? Any suggestions?

Comment: Try the `LEFT` function ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE(Code), 4)) as Code from YourTable;
```

Comment: Great, just tested your solution with Ganesh's, strange that yours is faster:
**Ganesh's:**
`/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 160,734  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.015 sec. (+ 0.406 sec. network) */`

**Yours**
`/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 160,734  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.000 sec. (+ 0.296 sec. network) */`

Answer (score 4):

Try this one...

**Syntax**

```
SELECT SubStr(myColumn, 1, LENGTH(myColumn) - 3)
FROM MyTable
```

**Example**

```
SELECT SubStr(code, 1, LENGTH(code) - 3)
    FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, which may be the most concise...

```
SELECT LEFT(Code, LENGTH(Code) - 3)
FROM   TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LEFT(field, LENGTH(field) - 3) FROM my_table
```